# How can I query whether each element inside an array match a collection field

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb to save user information. There is a `userId` field in that collection. I get many userIds in my application and saved as an array. I need to query whether all the userIds in that array exist in the collection. If not, find out all the missing ones. Is there one query command does the work? I don't want to query the userId one by one. So what is the better way to achieve this?

The user collection is very simple as below and there is no nested data.

```
userId: String
name: String
gender: String
phone: String
```

For example, I have an array of ids `[1, 2, 3]`. I have to run query three times to check whether these are users to match the three ids.

Comment: please provide a sample data set to understand whether u have nested arrays in the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) operator.

Example:

```
db.users.find( {userId: { $in: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } } );
```

Once you have the users pulled back from that you can determine in the application layer which users did not come back.

Comment: I think this query will find whether there is an userId in `1,2,3` array. But my question is that I have an array of userId, I want to know whether each id exists in the database. For example, I have `1,2,3`, I need to check whether there are users whose id is 1,2,3.

Comment: The $in operator performs an OR op in the database. Did you actually try it? This will return all docs that have userId of 1 OR 2 OR 3. By retrieving all those docs and comparing it to the array your originally supplied to the query you should be able to determine which users are already in your database.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I have accepted it. Thanks.